# Some items in Listview disappearing after switching commands

Tags: vb.net, listview

Good day. I've been struggling with my listview for a few days now. When I use the listview to show items from a query, it starts out ok and displays the proper information but when I start using it on a query for another table, I get an Overload Resolution error where it says that I can't convert DBNull to String. I added ".tostring" on every item so I could see the output.

Here is my listview sub

```
Public Sub ShowData()
    DTable.Clear()
    DSet.Tables.Add(New DataTable)
    SQLAd.SelectCommand = SQLComm
    SQLAd.Fill(DTable)


    For Each Row In DTable.Rows
        Search_List.ListView1.Items.Add(Row.Item(0).ToString)
        Search_List.ListView1.Items(Search_List.ListView1.Items.Count-  
1).SubItems.Add(Row.Item(1).ToString)
        Search_List.ListView1.Items(Search_List.ListView1.Items.Count- 
1).SubItems.Add(Row.Item(2).ToString)
    Next

End Sub
```

These are the codes for the first table queries:

```
 SQL_Close()
        SQL_Open
SQLComm = New SqlCommand("SELECT PatientID, LastName, GivenName FROM   
tbPatient WHERE Disable !='Y'and (PatientID = @PatientID or LastName =   
@LastName)   ", SQLCon)
        SQLComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientID", txtSearchPID.Text)
        SQLComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtSearchName.Text)
        SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Search_List.ListView1.Columns(0).Text = "Patient ID"
        Search_List.ListView1.Columns(1).Text = "Last Name"
        Search_List.ListView1.Columns(2).Text = "Given Name"
        ShowData()
        SQL_Close()
```

and

```
SQL_Close()
        SQL_Open()
        SQLComm = New SqlCommand("SELECT PatientID, LastName, GivenName FROM 
tbPatient WHERE Disable !='Y'and (PatientID = @PatientID or LastName =
@LastName)", SQLCon)
        SQLComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientID", txtSearchPID.Text)
        SQLComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtSearchName.Text)
        SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Search_List.ListView1.Columns(0).Text = "Patient ID"
        Search_List.ListView1.Columns(1).Text = "Last Name"
        Search_List.ListView1.Columns(2).Text = "Given Name"
        ShowData()
        SQL_Close()
```

If I cycle through these, they show all of the asked data but when I use this

```
  Search_List.Show()
        SQL_Close()
        SQL_Open()
        SQLComm = New SqlCommand("SELECT Username, Lastname, Privilege FROM
      WHERE (EmployeeID = @Employee or LastName = @LastName)", SQLCon)
        SQLComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee", txtSearchPID.Text)
        SQLComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtSearchName.Text)
        SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Search_List.ListView1.Columns(0).Text = "Username"
        Search_List.ListView1.Columns(1).Text = "LastName"
        Search_List.ListView1.Columns(2).Text = "Privilege"
        ShowData()
        SQL_Close()
```

Columns(0) and (2) are null. I don't understand how it returns null values because when I reversed the cycle (Search in tbAccounts then in tbPatient) the same thing happens.

Comment: Why you adding empty table to DSet? Are you clearing the Search_List.ListView1.Items somewhere because you are again only adding items into it?

Comment: It's not adding an empty table I believe. Yes, I'm clearing it while I'm moving through one menu to another. The only clear command I user is "Search_List.ListView1.Items.Clear()"

Comment: The SQL command text, "SELECT Username, Lastname, Privilege FROM WHERE (EmployeeID = @Employee or LastName = @LastName", is missing a table name value.

Comment: Wow. I did not see that. Thank you very much for pointing that out.